# In C#, I am getting an error when requesting permission for speech recognition Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, permissions, request, speech

So I am using the **Plugin.SpeechRecognition** Nuget Package and following the exact code on line and its not working.

I have tried adding the "Plugin.Permissions" Nuget Package and that hasn't helped and i have tried googling the problem but there isn't anyone getting this issue and it seems to work fine for everyone. I have also tried removing the "await" keyword and it just says

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'IObservable' and 'bool'

Here is my code:

```
    private async void GetSpeechPermission()
    {
        var granted = await CrossSpeechRecognition.Current.RequestPermission();
        if (granted == true)
        {
            // go!
        }
    }
```

so what should happen is there is no error what so ever and the code should run fine but the line of code

```
await CrossSpeechRecognition.Current.RequestPermission();
```

has a red underline saying

> IObservable' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'IObservable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

when I am using the EXACT code provided by the creator of the plugin from here https://github.com/aritchie/speechrecognition

Any help is MUCH appreciated!!

Comment: I would look at the sample app, I don't think the github docs are correct.

Comment: Solved! the solution was to add "using System.Reactive.Linq;" and add ".ToTask(); to the end of the offending line of code so resulting with "await CrossSpeechRecognition.Current.RequestPermission().ToTask();"

Thanx for your help! :D

Comment: okay not solved... got the same issue of 'Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'IObservable' and 'bool'' and the .ToTask(); as the developer suggested only created more issues so removed it.

Comment: did you look at the sample app like I suggested?

Comment: @Jason The sample is the same as above I just checked, Anyway Alex can you tell me your plugin version

Comment: okay so the plugin version is 1.0.0, the only version of the plugin. and i tried converting the "granted" variable to string and it is saying "NotSupported" as if its saying it isnt supported on my device which is wrong because its a nokia 6.1 runing android version 8.1 and googles search with voice works just fine so i know my phone is supported... i think the plugin its self is broken...

Comment: Solved! was missing permissions XD

Comment: If solved ,remember to post answer and mark it as accepted.^.^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution to this was to add

> using System.Reactive.Linq

in the using section of the code and instead of using a bool value as the code example for the plugin suggests, instead, in the if statement, convert the "granted" variable to a string and then check for "Available", Code:

```
    private async void GetSpeechPermission()
    {
        var granted = await CrossSpeechRecognition.Current.RequestPermission();
        if (granted.ToString() == "Available")
        {
            //GO
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps some one! :D